# Python - Scrapy, in a loop

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a small issue: I need for scrapy to loop a predetermined amount of times. The reason for this is that I am submitting a POST request and scraping the results. However, the results are not on one single page and thus needs to POST again with "cpipage" incremented. cpipage is the page number. Here is my spider code, I have changed the URL to nourl.com since this is not my website that I am scraping from.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
#from etmd.items import Etmditems
import scrapy

class EtmdSpider(Spider):
    name = "etmd"
    start_urls = ["http://b2.nourl.com/dp.asp"]
    def parse(self, response):
        url = "http://b2.nourl.com/dp.asp"
        payload = {"AppKey": "94921000e1999f84a518725", "ComparisonType1_1": "LIKE", "Value1_1": "", "MatchNull1_1" : "N", "ComparisonType2_1" : "LIKE", "MatchNull2_1" : "N", "Value2_1" : "", "ComparisonType3_1": "=", "MatchNull3_1" : "N", "Value3_1" : "", "x":"69", "y":"27", "FieldName1" : "County", "Operator1": "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails1": "1", "Operator2" : "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails2" : "1", "FieldName3": "Year", "Operator3" : "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails3": "1", "PageID" : "2", "GlobalOperator": "AND", "NumCriteria" : "3", "Search" : "1", "cpipage": "4"}
        return (FormRequest(url, formdata = payload, callback = self.parse_data))

    def parse_data(self, response):
        items = []
        sel = Selector(response)
        items.append(sel.xpath('//td').extract())

        exportfile = open( "exported.txt", "a")
        exportfile.write (str(items))

        print items
```

So within the payload dictionary I have the `cpipage` which in this case is "4" but I need it to increment all the way to 175. Is there anyway to do this within the code that I currently have or by running the scrapy spider though a script and no the shell?

I have already tried just a for loop:

```
for i in range(175):
    url = "http://b2.nourl.com/dp.asp"
    payload = {"AppKey": "94921000e1999f84a518725", "ComparisonType1_1": "LIKE", "Value1_1": "", "MatchNull1_1" : "N", "ComparisonType2_1" : "LIKE", "MatchNull2_1" : "N", "Value2_1" : "", "ComparisonType3_1": "=", "MatchNull3_1" : "N", "Value3_1" : "", "x":"69", "y":"27", "FieldName1" : "County", "Operator1": "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails1": "1", "Operator2" : "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails2" : "1", "FieldName3": "Year", "Operator3" : "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails3": "1", "PageID" : "2", "GlobalOperator": "AND", "NumCriteria" : "3", "Search" : "1", "cpipage": "%i" %i}
    return (FormRequest(url, formdata = payload, callback = self.parse_data))
```

Comment: Are you putting this for loop in your `parse` method of your spider?

Comment: yes i used it in `def parse(self,response)`

Comment: What happens when you run the loop you mentioned above?

Comment: I get only the first page

Comment: Yup, @warwurk 's answer was going to be my suggestion too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` statement will exit the method immediately.

You should either return list of all requests:

```
def parse(self, response):
    requests = []
    for i in range(175):
        url = "http://b2.nourl.com/dp.asp"
        payload = {"AppKey": "94921000e1999f84a518725", "ComparisonType1_1": "LIKE", "Value1_1": "", "MatchNull1_1" : "N", "ComparisonType2_1" : "LIKE", "MatchNull2_1" : "N", "Value2_1" : "", "ComparisonType3_1": "=", "MatchNull3_1" : "N", "Value3_1" : "", "x":"69", "y":"27", "FieldName1" : "County", "Operator1": "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails1": "1", "Operator2" : "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails2" : "1", "FieldName3": "Year", "Operator3" : "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails3": "1", "PageID" : "2", "GlobalOperator": "AND", "NumCriteria" : "3", "Search" : "1", "cpipage": "%i" %i}
        requests.append(FormRequest(url, formdata = payload, callback = self.parse_data))
    return requests
```

or `yield` them one by one:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for i in range(175):
        url = "http://b2.nourl.com/dp.asp"
        payload = {"AppKey": "94921000e1999f84a518725", "ComparisonType1_1": "LIKE", "Value1_1": "", "MatchNull1_1" : "N", "ComparisonType2_1" : "LIKE", "MatchNull2_1" : "N", "Value2_1" : "", "ComparisonType3_1": "=", "MatchNull3_1" : "N", "Value3_1" : "", "x":"69", "y":"27", "FieldName1" : "County", "Operator1": "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails1": "1", "Operator2" : "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails2" : "1", "FieldName3": "Year", "Operator3" : "OR", "NumCriteriaDetails3": "1", "PageID" : "2", "GlobalOperator": "AND", "NumCriteria" : "3", "Search" : "1", "cpipage": "%i" %i}
        yield FormRequest(url, formdata = payload, callback = self.parse_data)
```